# How do you read 4, 6, 8 bytes from a known offset in c#?

Tags: c#

File offset | Value:
0x2274 = 0F
0x2276 = 63

I'm trying to read offset 2274 to 2276; however, it's not reading out correctly.

```
//read Binary
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filepath));

//Name Change
long nameoffset = Convert.ToInt64(0x2274, 16);
br.BaseStream.Position = nameoffset;
namevalues = br.ReadByte().ToString("X4");

string GetName = Convert.ToString("NameChg");
if (GetName == "NameChg")
{

    long myvalue = Convert.ToInt64(namevalues, 16);
    MessageBox.Show("Current Name: " + Convert.ToString(myvalue));
}
```

the result return as "0015". I need the result to return as "‭25359‬".

Comment: You want to read 2 bytes, but you're only reading one `br.ReadByte()`. Use [`Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.8) instead

Comment: The integer literal `0x2274` is already the "correct" integer value `8820`, you don't need to use `Convert` there. And what are you trying to do with the `"NameChg"` and `Convert.ToString()` call there? You are comparing `"NameChg"` with `"NameChg"` which is always `true`.

Comment: Converting 0x0F + 0x63 to 9915 makes little sense.  0x0F63 == 3939, 0x630F == 25359.  Resolve that first.

Comment: HansPassant - You're correct. The actual answer should be '‭25359‬' in decimal. The offset I listed there will also be replaced by an ini variable.
Progman - the NameChg will be replaced with a variable from an ini file.

I just need to know how I can read 4bytes and above.

Answer (score 0):

solve my own puzzle. I got puzzled for a couple of days now. Below is an example of my codes for anyone who's looking to do the same. If you know of a better way to shorten these codes; feel free to post it.

```
        //This is where you'll code to load the binary file.
        var filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Test.bin");

        //read Binary
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filepath));
        string namevalues = null;
        //test offset purposes
        for (int i = 0x2274; i <= 0x2276; i++)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Position = i;
            namevalues += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");

        }
        br.Close();

        //put binary hex to array
        string newStr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(namevalues), ".{2}", "$0,");
        newStr = newStr.TrimEnd(',');
        string[] NewBytes = newStr.Split(',').ToArray();

        //Reverse order in Array
        Array.Reverse(NewBytes);
        newStr = NewBytes[0] + NewBytes[1] + NewBytes[2];
        int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(newStr, 16);
        String decValue2 = Convert.ToString(decValue);

        //test output
        messagebox.show(decValue2);
```